# How to convert a list into a data frame while keeping its headers in R

Tags: r, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a a list called `mylist`, in it there are 108 rows apart from the headers. I tried converting it to a dataframe and it successfully worked using the following command

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(mylist), nrow=108, byrow=F))
```

However, the headers for each matrix in my list (mylist) have not been defined in my new dataframe df.

```
names(df)
```

is

```
"X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5" "X6" "X7" "X8" "X9" "X10" "X11" "X12" "X13" "X14" "X15" "X16" "X17" "X18" "X19" "X20" "X21" "X22" "X23" "X24" "X25" "X26" "X27" "X28" "X29" "X30" "X31" "X32" "X33" "X34" "X35" "X36"
```

`mylist` looks something like so

```
head(mylist[[1]])

      RAmi         MDaf
1   11.806405   -3.588567
2   7.711101    -9.721415
3   2.315104    11.217575
4   20.372999   -2.267938
5   22.279704   -1.668082
6   13.57909    20.67355



head(mylist[[2]])

          Tomi         Rahaf
    1     325          -3
    2      71          -9
    3      2           11
    4     20.999      -22
    5      22         -16
    6     139         2065
```

this is only for `head(mylist[[i]])` when `i=1` but there exist similar things for i=1,2,3, ... , 18

What I want is to put them all in one dataframe adjacently. It worked fine but I am having a problem with the heading

I hope one may help me with understanding how to do so. 
Thank you

Comment: Show `mylist` or a facsimile that illustrates the problem...

Comment: It is very long how may I show it to you

Comment: Use a different list that is similar enough to illustrate the problem. There is no such thing as a "header" or a "row" for a list, so what you're asking is quite unclear without an example. For advice on making a reproducible example, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/

Comment: This could be as simple as `names(df) <- names(mylist)`, and if it's not that simple then you haven't given us enough information to support further coding.

Comment: names(mylist) is null (no reason why). I edit it based on your request

Comment: Can you show us the second element in your list? This may just need `rbind` or `cbind`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a problem in converting a list of dataframes into one dataframe. Therefore, it would be better to work with one dataframe from the very beginning.

For example, in my case i imported the raw data

```
#data1=read.csv(file.choose(), header=F)
data1=read.csv
```

Then afterwards I started analysing my data. I then wrote a code to generate a dataframe as in

```
# Here we are extracting the data which we wish to have
#iterations=nrow(data1) #Check the number of rows

listOfDataFrames <- vector(mode = "list", length = 18)   # define a dataframe with length
#mylist <- list() #create an empty list
for (k in 0:17)
{
    j=18 # from 14 i.e. switzerland this is not true anymore 
    if ((k>=14) && (k<16))
    {
        f=7+j*k
        s=3+j*k

    }  else if (k<14)
    {
        s=7+j*k-4
        f=7+j*k
    } else if (k==16)
    {
        f=j*k+5
        s=f+4
    } else if (k==17)
    {
        f=304
        s=301
    }
    b= data1[,c(f,s)] 
    #mylist[[k+1]] <- b
    listOfDataFrames[[k+1]]=b
}
#df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(mylist), nrow=108, byrow=F))
```

This allowed me to put all the data into one dataframe along with the headers

```
df=do.call("cbind", listOfDataFrames)
head(df)
```